# restRequest does not contain a definition for ConfigureWebRequest

Tags: c#, restsharp

With this new version of RestRequest I get the following message restRequest does not contain a definition for ConfigureWebRequest

[image]

What should I call it now?

```
public async Task Login()
                {
                try
                    {
                       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate {
                        return true;
                        };
                    var url = "https://192.0.0.0:50000/b1s/v1/Login";
                    var client = new RestClient(url);
                    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);
    
                    request.ConfigureWebRequest(r => { r.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; });
    
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.AddHeader("B1S-WCFCompatible", "true");
                    request.AddHeader("B1S-MetadataWithoutSession", "true");
                    request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                    var body = new
                        {
                        CompanyDB = "Prueba",
                        Password = "****",
                        UserName = "Hackerman"
                        };
                    var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                    request.AddParameter("application/json", x, ParameterType.RequestBody);             
                    RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
                    var output = response.Content;
                    MessageBox.Show(output + response.ErrorException.Message + response.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to upgrade? V107 is a major release work breaking changes. See [the docs](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107) for the new way.

Comment: I am not clear The documentation does not explain specifically what to do with ConfigureWebRequest :(

Comment: That's because it seems there is no specific case. So much has changed, that you have to approach it differently. The whole way of configuring has changed.